# Handle multidimensional json array

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How can I access the key and values of this object?

```
{
  "chat_data": {
    "nickname": "somevalue",
    "items": {
        "FncZ9Q": [{
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3",
            "key4": "value4",
            "key5": "value5"
        }, {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3",
            "key4": "value4",
            "key5": "value5"
        }, {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3",
            "key4": "value4",
            "key5": "value5"
        }],
        "GYDjsA": [{
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3",
            "key4": "value4",
            "key5": "value5"
        }, {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3",
            "key4": "value4",
            "key5": "value5"
        }]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried some techniques but I don't know how I solve this issue by myself.
Here is my ajax call where the data should be managed.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/dataUrl",
    type: "post",
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        for (var key in data.chat_data.items) {
            var obj = data.chat_data.items[key];
            $.each(data.chat_data.items, function (i, value) {
                console.log('Value of ' + i + ' is : ' + value);
            })
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

I hope someone can help me out.
Regards Sascha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop. Loop. And loop one more time.

```js
var data = JSON.parse('{"chat_data":{"nickname":"somevalue","items":{"FncZ9Q":[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"value4","key5":"value5"},{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"value4","key5":"value5"},{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"value4","key5":"value5"}],"GYDjsA":[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"value4","key5":"value5"},{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"value4","key5":"value5"}]}}}');

for (var key in data.chat_data.items) {
    var obj = data.chat_data.items[key];
    log('Item "' + key + '":');
    for (var index in obj) {
        var obj2 = obj[index], list = [];
        for (var prop in obj2) {
            list.push('"' + prop + '": "' + obj2[prop] + '"');
        }
        log('    Object at index ' + index + '=> ' + list.join(', '));
    }
}

function log(txt){ document.body.innerHTML += '<pre>' + txt + '</pre>'; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok this works but how i can get the Obj2 property and values in one row ?

Comment: I have created some variables in the Last for Loop but on every time the variables Are empty

Comment: @SaschaHeim I changed my answer to output them in one row. If it is still not working for you, please create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) so I can look at it.

Comment: Its working but i created a object instead of pushing it, so it is accesable over object notation many thanks made my day

Answer (score 2):

You have to use three nested loops, like that:

```
for (const i in data.chat_data.items) {
  for (const j of data.chat_data.items[i]) {
    for (const key in j) {
      const value = j[key]
      console.log(key, value)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We pretty much have the same answer (so, +1), but I'd just like to ask: why use `const` where `var` would also work? `const` is still pretty new, and not supported everywhere (e.g.: IE10).

Comment: @blex Using `const` instead of `var` prevents you from accidentally overwriting a variable. It's true that it's not supported everywhere, but you can use Babel to compile ES6 code into ES5.

Comment: Oh, ok, I can see where that would be useful (`for(const i in arr){ setTimeout(foo, 10*i); }`)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) it is easy to install and use

```
_.allKeys(object)
```

Retrieve all the names of object's own and inherited properties.

hope it helps

Comment: can i get also the values with this method ?

Comment: this methos is only for getting the keys, but if you check the link you will see a lot of functions for collections and object. I have used many times and Im telling you, underscore will make your life better